# Flutter: app crashes when 2 alert dialogs are pops

Tags: flutter, dart

If you quickly click on two cards, a black screen will appear, and the application will have to be restarted

*Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision adc687823a (2 weeks ago) • 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
Engine • revision b09f014e96
Tools • Dart 2.12.3*

**Scaffold**

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
                child: GFCard('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')),
            onTap: Alerts.correct(context),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            child: GFCard('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),
            onTap: Alerts.wrong(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Alerts**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Alerts {
  static correct(BuildContext context) {
    return () => _alert(context,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF25C047), message: 'Correct ');
  }

  static wrong(BuildContext context) {
    return () => _alert(context,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFC22121), message: 'Wrong :(');
  }

   static _alert(BuildContext context, {Color backgroundColor, String message}) {
    return showDialog(
      barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => Navigator.of(context).pop());
        return AlertDialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
          content: Text(
            message,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          elevation: 24,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

````
E/flutter ( 5535): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 5535): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 5535): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.```
````

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you should set `barrierDismissible: false` in the showDialog()